# php - Insert doesn't enter values to form

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guys i dont know what im doing wrong but my tables are correct, php error is on and it doesnt insert

[image]

I can get both first name and email echoed

```
 <?php 
 if (isset($_POST['subs'])) {


 function html_escape($html_escape) {
    $html_escape =  htmlspecialchars($html_escape, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8');
    return $html_escape;
    }   


    $name=html_escape($_POST['name']); 
    $email=html_escape($_POST['email']);


   if (empty($name) || empty($email)) {echo"<div class='alert alert-danger'>Please enter both name and email address</div>";}

   else {

    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
   echo"<div class='alert alert-danger'>Invalid email address, please enter a correct email address!</div>";
    }

        else {

 echo "INSERT into subs (first_name, email) VALUES ('$name','$email')";
 $insert=mysql_query("INSERT into subs (first_name, email) VALUES ('$name','$email')");
  if ($insert) {echo"<div class='alert alert-success'>Thank you for subscribing with us</div>";}
     }

 }}
 ?>
```

Comment: We need more code to figure out the problem.. This is like saying you have an itch on your body and only showing your head..

Comment: this query is fine, might be that you're not connected to `mysql`

Comment: @Naruto that's a weird comparison. Neelde in a haystack.

Comment: try to echo and check your query. If it has the proper field values `echo "INSERT into subs (first_name, email) VALUES ('$name','$email')"` or not.

Comment: @Daan I was looking for something better, but that wouldn' bet allowed to be posted here.. :D

Comment: another thing to take into consideration (it won't fix your issue directly) but, mysql_x has been deprecated. Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: I don't see any database connection!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, are you connected to mysql before running your query?

```
$conn=mysql_connect('localhost', 'your_db_username', 'your_db_password');
if(!$conn){
   die('Cannot connect to mysql');
}
mysql_select_db('your_db_name');
```

Then, when you're sure you're connected to the db and your query is still not working, add `or die(mysql_error())` after your query like this, this will help you know what's going wrong with your insert:

```
$insert=mysql_query("INSERT into subs (first_name, email) 
        VALUES ('$name','$email')")
        or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: I have that already but doesnt give me any errors, am i using a reserved word?

Answer (score 0):

As a general point, using the PDO class is preferred, and may give you more information about what the problem is.

e.g.

```
$pdo = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=<database_name>', '<database_username>', '<database_password>');

$sql = "INSERT into subs (first_name, email) VALUES (:name,:email)";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);    
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$result = $stmt->execute();
```

This gives a lot of benefits. Take my word for it, or give "benefits of PDO" a quick Google.

Comment: I agree, my hands are tight here and cant do much, just repairing this for someone

Answer (score 0):

$query = "INSERT INTO subs (first_name, email) VALUES ('" . $name . "','" . $email . "') ";

$insert = mysql_query($query);

Comment: check your column name in table ; is it the same

Comment: I did check that, im attaching image

Comment: echo $query, and then take that query and run it in your SQL editor

Comment: it did insert in sql but not here

Comment: Check your connection object

Comment: I have checked your table; 90% i am sure that there is mistake in your connection object

Comment: Same connection object is inserting other queries